# How to serialize/archive the state of game objects that require pointers to each other?

Tags: ios, serialization

How can I serialize and archive the state of game objects into a database when they require pointers to each other? Is there a way to serialize custom objects beyond just primitive data types? Should I be archiving the pointers? Or would a better approach be to give each object an unique ID so I can rebuild the relationship later?

I'm hoping someone can breakdown the general approach I should be taking for saving an iOS game to the server for later retrieval by other devices/players. I know this seems broad, but I'm just looking for the bullet point break down of the technologies/libraries/classes I should be using.

The game has already be developed, I'm just not sure how to save and encrypt the state server side. I'm thinking of using AFNetworking, but I need to save all the objects of a relatively complex game. It seems a JSON object with primitive data types won't cut it.

Comment: 'Saving' pointers is always a bad idea, in my opinion, because they'll never be the same. If you want to serialize relationships, you will need a unique-ID approach.

Comment: You'd be surprised how far JSON can take you. Not only I serialize nigh-unrestricted object graphs (in Python, which has *nothing* but pointers) to JSON[1], the code doing it is simple enough to be generated programatically. ([1]: Actually YAML for readability, but I only use atoms, arrays and dicts, so I could - and in fact did in the past - use JSON.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use core data.  That's why it is there.  Straight from their docs...

> The Core Data framework provides generalized and automated solutions
>   to common tasks associated with object life-cycle and object graph
>   management, including persistence.

Intro to Core Data Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html